# Question with regards to tangent spaces to the intersection of two 2-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying solve a question from the text Mathematical Analysis: An Introduction by Andrew Browder.  On page 266 in chapter 11 on Manifolds, question 10, it asks

Let $\ M\ $and$\ N\ $be 2-manifolds in$\ {\mathbb{R}}^{3}. \ $  Show that if the tangent spaces to $\ M\ $and$\ N\ $do not conincide at any point of$\ M\cap\ N,\ $then$\ M\cap\ N\ $is a 1-manifold, and the tangent line to$\ M\cap\ N\ $at $\ p\in\ M\cap\ N\ $is the intersection of the tangent planes to$\ M\ $and$\ N\ $at$\ p.\ $

I am having trouble with the wording of the premise of the question. What does it mean for tangent spaces to manifolds M and N to not intersect?  Does it mean that the set of vectors that form the basis of null spaces derivative matrix for M and N respectively consist two different set of basis vectors. Intuitively the intersection of two 2-manifolds automatically make it either a curve or a set of two different curves.

Comment: It says "do not *coincide*".

Comment: @AmitaiYuval, I think then iI am a bit confused with the wording.  Do two tangent spaces not coinciding mean the same as two tangent vectors being equal?

Comment: We say the two tangent spaces coincide if they are the same space. In the question they do not coincide, that is, they are not the same space. For two $2$-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^3$, this means that the manifolds are transverse.

Comment: $Amital Yuval,
Thank you for the reply.  Sorry for my late response.  I tried looking up online to try to understand more about transverse intersection of two manifolds of same dimension.  When you say that two tangent spaces to every points to two different manifolds respectively, saying they are not the same is equivalent to them as mutually orthogonal vector spaces,  This would also mean that the two tangent spaces form a direct sum.  Is that correct? What about at the points where the two manifolds intersect?   How does that affect the two tangent spaces which don't intersect.